# How to upgrade angular from 4.2.4 to 4.4.6?

Tags: angular

I installed angular with using npm install @angular/core@4.4.6 but it not reflecting in package.json.

Answer (score 1):

Try `npm install --save @angular/core@4.4.6`

Without --save it just installs the new package into `node_modules/` but doesn't update the package.json file.

Comment: without --save it installs the packages globally not project specific

Answer (score 0):

You can go to your package.json and change all 4.2.4 versions to 4.4.6 and then do 'npm install'.